# How to extract the value of "shadow$_klass_" as "String Type"?

Tags: java, android

I want to output the value of "shadow$*klass*" as "String type".

I tried all methods available in "java.lang.class", but failed to extract the desired value.

How to print the value of "shadow$*klass*"?

The image is the value of the "shadow$*klass*" object that can be checked in android studio debug.

[image]

I tried running all methods available in "java.lang.class".

As a result, I thought that the values of the "shadow$c_klass_" object could be output as "String type".

However, I could only get other object values or the package name of the parent class.

-add contents-

I want to get the "classSize" value of "java.lang.class".

However, "classSize" is declared private.

[image]

What method can I use to get that value?

-Methods (get...) for obtaining values ​​were not implemented in the class.

Comment: What would that string look like? In other words, what is the result you want to obtain for this specific case?

Comment: As you can see in the picture above, the "shadow$_klass_" object has various values such as "classFlags" and "accessFlags".

I am currently studying Android objects.

By collecting these various values, we try to identify common characteristics of Java classes.

Of course, you can do this manually.

However, I would like to pull that data from a vast amount of wild apps.

Comment: I was able to extract the desired value by writing code like this:

This code is written in Kotlin.
{\n
val tmp_class = Tmp_class()\n
val vo = tmp_class.javaClass.declaredFields.get(3) // In the result value (list) of declaredFields, ClassSize had the 3rd index value.\n

vo.setAccessible(true)\n
val name = vo.name // "classSize"\n
val value = vo.get(tmp_class) // "272"\n
}